# Как произошло слово "филонить"?

Tags: этимология

Интересно, как произошло слово "филонить"? Может, был какой-то Филон, который отлынивал от работы?

Comment: Посмотрите http://ru-etymology.livejournal.com/1299974.html

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов: ФИЛО́Н, -а, м. (прост.). Лентяй, лодырь.(С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова Толковый словарь русского языка). Отсюда "филонить" - лентяйничать, лодырничать.

Answer (score 0):

Это не от английского "felon" или французского "félon"?
Оба слова очень старые. Сходные корни в значении "злой человек, негодяй, преступник" есть в средневековом английском, прото-германском и в латыни

From Middle English felun, feloun, from Anglo-Norman felun (“traitor, wretch”), from Medieval Latin fellō, from Frankish *fellō (“wicked person”), from Proto-Germanic *fillô, *filjô (“flayer, whipper, scoundrel”), from Proto-Germanic *faluz (“cruel, evil”) (compare English fell (“fierce”), Middle High German vālant (“imp”)), related to *fellaną (compare Dutch villen, German fillen (“to whip, beat”), both from Proto-Indo-European *pelh₂- (“to stir, move, swing”) (compare Old Irish ad·ella (“to seek”), di·ella (“to yield”), Umbrian pelsatu (“to overcome, conquer”), Latin pellō (“to drive, beat”), Latvian lijuôs, plītiês (“to force, impose”), Ancient Greek πέλας (pélas, “near”), πίλναμαι (pílnamai, “I approach”), Old Armenian հալածեմ (halacem, “I pursue”).